# Could someone help me with testing my MQTT?

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt

So on my first Raspberry Pi, I have:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost - v -t test_channel
```

And on my second Raspberry Pi, I did `hostname -I`, got the IP address of my pi, and did:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 172.#.#.# -t test_channel - m "Hello From Other Pi"
```

I don't see an output on my first Pi. Did I do something wrong in the terminal?

Comment: This is difficult to answer without more info. I'd suggest you look at your broker logs (assuming Mosquitto try [`log_type all`](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)). This should enable you to see log entries as each Pi connects and messages are transferred. If that does not help please edit your question and include the logs (along with broker version and config) and the output from both commands. Also please be sure that both Pi's are communicating with the same broker (it's not really clear from your question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is most likely that you have picked the wrong IP address for your first pi.

The `172.x.x.x` IP address is most likely the address of your internal docker bridge. If the address is actually `172.17.0.1` this is definitely the case.

Rather that using the `hostname -I`, I suggest you run `ip a` and pick the address assigned to either `eth0` or `wlan0` (depending on how your pi is connected to the local network). On most home networks this is likely to start with `192.168.x.x` to `10.x.x.x`.

Also it is not clear from your question where you ran `hostname -I`, it is implied that you ran this on the second pi, but you need to run it on the first pi, then use the output on the second pi.